# IntelliJ Idea JavaFX debugging issue

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, javafx

Debugging in IntelliJ idea for JavaFX has been a pain for me. Mainly because when I setup a breakpoint, IntelliJ will just show me all the backend class files that I don't care about.

Is there a way to stop it from happening? I've tried stepping over but that doesn't work.

Here's an example of what happens when I debug a `getText()` method.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zSoX.png

Any help?

Comment: What does it mean **stepping over doesn't work**?

Comment: In visual studio when you click the step out button, it will skip the line and step out. I thought it was the same for IntelliJ

Comment: It is not skip the line, just don't go into method. **Step Over** binded as **F8** must do that. Idk why it's not working to you. You can try to use **Force Step Over**.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a breakpoint after the method and use f9 (resume program) so intellij skips the method you dont wan't to see!

It's not a fix, just a workaround.