# Mouse doesn't work during debugging JavaFX projects in idea is running on KDE 5

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, javafx, kde-plasma

When I am debugging JavaFX project and debugging process stops on a breakpoint i can't use a mouse. I can move the cursor on the screen, but left, right buttons and wheel don't work. More than, the mouse doesn't work system-wild: if I switch an active window the mouse won't work in this window too. Keyboard works well.

I use:

---

- IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.3
- Build #IU-162.1812.17, built on August 30, 2016
- JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b287 amd64
- JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

---

- KDE Plasma 5.5.1
- QT 5.5.1
- Kernel 4.4.0.36-generic

---

```
→ java -version 

java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

Also, this issue appeared on other DEs (xfce) and different hardware (on my laptop).

Comment: One year ago : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329938/intellij-idea-javafx-debugging-issue

Comment: @TowfikAlrazihi - This is a different issue.   

Axazeano - I have the same issue on Gnome - I think it's a bug with JavaFX implementation on Linux, although I'm not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solution is listed here: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=253594

To use this in IntelliJ - Go to Run -> Edit Configurations, and add:

```
-Dglass.disableGrab=true
```

to VM Options.

Edit: Heads up - this messes with Drag/Drop events, possibly causing them to not work or work unexpectedly. If you are implementing drag/drop this solution is problematic.